# How do I can print shared dependencies of ios app in Linux

Tags: ios, linux, lldb, ldd

I want to print shared object dependencies of ios app in linux script for crash parsing.

But I am getting following error while executing commands.
1)
`ldd ./demoApp.app`
not a regular file
2)
`ldd ./demoApp.ipa`
not a dynamic executable
3)
`ldd ./demoApp.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/demoApp`
not a dynamic executable

What argument I should pass to ldd to print the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used ldd (I don't use Linux), but I would start with `man ldd` to determine appropriate arguments. Also `ldd ./demoApp.app/demoApp` should get you past the error messages above.

1. *demoApp.app* is an app bundle, which is a directory hierarchy
   containing the executable, resources, etc.;
2. *demoApp.ipa* is a zip-compressed file containing the app bundle, used for cases like uploading the app to the App Store; and
3. *demoApp.app.dSYM* is a file system package (directory hierarchy) that includes the app's symbol data

Comment: `ldd ./demoApp.app/demoApp` is also giving error as not a dynamic executable

Comment: Does ldd work with Mach-O executables? If not then that could be the reason for this error.

Answer (score 0):

It would surprise me if ldd supports mach-o and the darwin loader formats, and you seem to have demonstrated that it doesn't...

OTOH, lldb is generally built to support reading mach-o object files on linux, so you could use it.

The direct shared library dependencies are stored in the "load commands" of a mach-o binary, and lldb will read those.  So just start up lldb, do `target create` for your .app bundle, and `image list` will show you the direct dependencies.  lldb will recurse through all the direct dependencies to find the closure of the dependencies for that .app, but to do that you would have to have all the directly dependent libraries available (since their dependencies are in the "load commands" of the dependent libraries.) I'm not sure how you would get your hands on those.